# Как сделать поиск и замену в тексте?

Tags: javascript

Есть HTML текст, в котором встречаются несколько `[]`.

Также есть массив такого вида:

```
[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
```

То есть в каждый "блок" `[]` в тексте должен вставиться (по индексу) соответствующий массив.

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать это (без jquery), а то у меня ничего не выходит. Максимум чего я достиг - это получил массив "блоков" `[]`, но никак не могу заменить их в тексте, чтобы на выходе получить исходный текст с заменой.

Comment: вообще ничего не понял...  выложи код...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто:

```js
let arr = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]], pointer = 0;

let wrapper = document.querySelector('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = wrapper.innerHTML.replace(/\[\]/g, _ => (_ = arr[pointer].toString(), pointer++, _));
```

```css
span{
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div>Это первый массив: <span>[]</span>, тут уже второй: <span>[]</span><br />
А это третий: <span>[]</span></div>
```

---

На будущее - старайтесь выкладывать свои наработки, а то выглядит как попрошайничество, а не просьба помочь.